# jQuery .hasClass method to omit effect

Tags: jquery, class

I've created a simple background effect for some tabs on a page but don't want that effect to fire if the tab has the class 'current'.

I presume there is a way to do this using .hasClass

Here's what I'm using for the effect:

```
$('ul.htabs a').mouseover(function(){

 $(this).stop().animate(
  {backgroundPosition:"(0 -810px)"}, 
  {duration:150},
  {easing: 'easeOutCubic'})
 }).mouseout(function(){
 $(this).stop().animate(
  {backgroundPosition:"(0 -806px)"}, 
  {duration:150},
  {easing: 'easeInCubic'})
 });
```

Comment: Does the `current` class get added dynamically, or is it present on page load?

Comment: it gets added dynamically, yes

Answer (score 4):

You could also put it in the selector:

```
$('ul.htabs:not(.current) a').mouseover(function(){ ... });
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would work if the `current` class is being added dynamically to the elements. It does work if the event handlers are assigned using `.live()`. But using `.bind()` the handler stays with the element even if the selector is changed.

Comment: @patrick - this is likely to be a good solution for a static page load but you are correct.  If this is intended to be done such that current gets applied dynamically this will not work without a live query.  Also I hadn't realized live had been added to core, that's totally sweet.  I need to catch up here.

Comment: I should note though that this is a good solution assuming that that the OP doesn't expect the handler to follow along with adding/removing the `current` class. I was making perhaps too much of an assumption.

Comment: @Jonathan - Yeah, I perhaps was making the classic blunder one makes when they assume. *(If you know what I mean.)*

Answer (score 2):

```
.mouseover(function(e) {

if ( $(this).hasClass('lol') ) {
  return;
}
```

if the element has a class of `lol` kill the function by returning immediately.

Comment: While I agree with this answer I don't think  you have offered up enough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector:

```
$('ul.htabs:not(.current) a').mouseover(function(){
    // ... your code here
});
```

Now, if the class `current` is added or removed dynamically (Thanks [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/184499/matt)!) to the `<a>` tag, this will produce confusing results, as when the mouseover event is bound that list of elements is static. If you are also applying the class `current` on the fly, then use [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to bind the event, so that you only ever get anchors that at that moment have the `current` class applied:

```
$('ul.htabs:not(.current) a').live('mouseover', function(){
    // ... your code here
});
```